# In VS 2019 - How to regenerate code-behind and designer files from an existing aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I imported in my project Web c# an aspx page, for example, mypage.aspx,  with HTML code. This page is very simple.

All I want is to generate the 2 files (in IDE) aspx.cs and designer.cs (mypage.aspx.cs and mypage.aspx.designer.cs).

I tried "Convert to web project" functionality but it does not work.

Any idea, please?

Of course, I read several solutions on this site but none worked (with vs 2019).

Comment: Some ASPX pages don't have the code behind. Pay attention to the `CodeFile` attribute in your `Page` directive, if it's empty (not there), there's no code behind.

Comment: @Victor, or the CodeBehind attribute depending on his scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no actual code in the original code-behind file then it's pretty easy to do. Create a new page of the same name. Then just copy and paste the markup from the original, taking care to leave the newly-created page directive as is.

If there was logic in your original code-behind then you're out of luck. You might try decompiling the original DLL and try to re-create the original code that way.

Comment: Thanks Irish.

I know this method and it works...but I wanted a more automatic method, because I have sevral pages aspx.

Thanks anyway